# Spark SQL loads data without configuring Hive?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I read JSON in Spark, however, I had some warning that I received regarding Hive. I did not set the Hive on my laptop. The code I used was:

```
scala> val dfs = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM json.`/Users/name/Desktop/constituents.json`")
21/12/18 23:48:08 WARN HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.stats.jdbc.timeout does not exist
21/12/18 23:48:08 WARN HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.stats.retries.wait does not exist
21/12/18 23:48:13 WARN ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 2.3.0
21/12/18 23:48:13 WARN ObjectStore: setMetaStoreSchemaVersion called but recording version is disabled: version = 2.3.0, comment = Set by MetaStore shashanksathish@127.0.0.1
21/12/18 23:48:13 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
21/12/18 23:48:14 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException
21/12/18 23:48:14 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database json, returning NoSuchObjectException
dfs: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Name: string, Sector: string ... 1 more field]
```

I couldn't understand how the data loaded into my variable.

Answer (score 0):

Many sites use Spark with Spark created/only tables or just HDFS directories. Hive is not needed with Spark and this is just a warning. This is different to not needing Hadoop.

For parquet and delta no Hive metadata aspects are needed in terms of Hive Metastore.

If you need Ranger Security st row level you will need Hive external tables.